# Chain ng-repeat item transitions

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I have a simple scope of a list of names:

```
$scope.friends = [
    {name:'John'},
    {name:'Jessie'},
    {name:'Johanna'},
    {name:'Joy'},
    {name:'Mary'},
    {name:'Peter'},
    {name:'Sebastian'},
    {name:'Erika'},
    {name:'Patrick'},
    {name:'Samantha'}
  ];
```

I perform a simple `ng-repeat` over these items, and display on my front end. What i want to try to achieve is that each item/name transitions in, one after each other, like a chain.

The closet to the effect i have seen can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/57uGQ/ however this uses jQuery libraries which i want to avoid.

I am using the ng-animate library if that helps?

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aGwEe2jlGBTvjoSsiK9p?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `ng-if`, `$timeout` and the `.ng-enter-stagger` css class to replicate the effect in the jsfiddle example.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="repeatController">
  <ul>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-if="!hidden">
      {{friend.name}},
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate']).controller('repeatController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.friends = [
      {name:'John'},
      {name:'Jessie'},
      {name:'Johanna'},
      {name:'Joy'},
      {name:'Mary'},
      {name:'Peter'},
      {name:'Sebastian'},
      {name:'Erika'},
      {name:'Patrick'},
      {name:'Samantha'}
    ];
  $scope.hidden = true;
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.hidden = false;
  }, 10);   
});
```

css:

```
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}
.animate-repeat.ng-enter-stagger {
  transition-delay: 1.2s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
.animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hu5Usmw9IJSw0ALf5XX8?p=preview)

Comment: Hm... how come you need to push things to the queue with a timeout here? I thought ng-animate handled that.?

Comment: `ng-animate` only fires on `ng-repeat` elements ["when a new item is added to the list or when an item is revealed after a filter"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations).

Comment: Oh right, it doesn't trigger on first load since then any element would get an entry animation on first load. Makes sense.

Comment: Exactly. It'd be nice if there was an option to make it fire on first load, but this is the closest I can get to that happening.